# I can not get rid of information about a file transfer

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer

Hi I have HTC phone with Android system. Several days ago I tried to transfer a picture from another phone by bluetooth. Now I can't to delete a notice about transfer.
I mean that when I click on transfer notice and I next click on accept or discard this notice is still visible.

Any suggestion?

Comment: i did restart my phone to default settings. This is not solution but it's work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing all notifications. There is a button, my phone is in Spanish but I guess in English it should say "Clear" or "Remove all" something like that.